# An element that only exists in one HTML file, stops all my other HTML files from running JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have 5 HTML all linked to 1 only JS and 1 only CSS. Everything in the same folder.

In one of the HTML files, there's a `div` with class grid-colors. I wrote a `for loop` that accesses this grid-colors `div` and it works fine. However, all my other HTML files throw an error in the console that says Uncaught TypeError: gridColors is null. I guess Javascript tries to find the grid-colors `div` in the file that is open but it only exists in one HTML file. How can i make sure javascript looks for this class only in one File? or how can I solve this error?

**HTML where the element works**

```
<div class="grid-colors"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
const gridColors = document.querySelector(".grid-colors");
for (let i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    const item = document.createElement("div");
    item.classList.add("color-grid-item");
    gridColors.appendChild(item);
}
```

Comment: Wrap the code in a conditional that checks if the element is not null, so that way it only runs if it is not null.

Answer (score 3):

Conditional to check if the element is not null should get rid of your issue.

```
const gridColors = document.querySelector(".grid-colors");
if (gridColors !== null) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    const item = document.createElement("div");
    item.classList.add("color-grid-item");
    gridColors.appendChild(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Your other HTML files do not have a `gridColors` element. If you defined the code in the global scope without a function, the only way of doing this would be to check if the `gridColors` variable is `null`, if it is, then you break out of the `for` loop.

```js
const gridColors = document.querySelector(".grid-colors");
for (let i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    if(!gridColors) break; //escapes the error
    const item = document.createElement("div");
    item.classList.add("color-grid-item");
    gridColors.appendChild(item);
}
```

2. If the code resides inside a `function` in your JS file, and you only need to call the function inside a specific HTML page, use the `onload` function for that HTML page like this:

```
<body onload="theFunction()">
...
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a local scope variable, you will need to use var, not const.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

```
var gridColors = document.querySelector(".grid-colors");
for (let i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement("div");
    item.classList.add("color-grid-item");
    gridColors.appendChild(item);
}
```

Comment: but how the scope of variable in the JS file will help? he will continue to get the error in all others 4 html files, because of lacking of the desired element, only null checking can help here as already answered.

Comment: @Xth yeah scope does not help 
This issue did not occur with other elements I guess because I managed them all through functions
But I'm wondering now... Will I always have to ask if the variable is null so that the code runs properly?

Comment: @AlanRothmanMariñoCruel i think yes, because in your code you add class to div element, and you can't add it to nothing if your element doesn't exist